# pyotp fails sometimes in production

Tags: python

I'm using [pyotp](https://github.com/nathforge/pyotp). But it fails sometimes in production. To replicate it, I have written the below test:

```
import pyotp
from time import sleep

key = pyotp.random_base32()
for i in range(10):
  otp = pyotp.TOTP(key).now()
  sleep(5)
  print pyotp.TOTP(key).verify(otp)
```

Sample output is:

```
True
False
True
True
True
True
True
False
True
True
```

I'm not able to debug what is going wrong here since it works 8/10 times. Why it fails 2/10?

Thank you,

Comment: Wow, totp feels like a disaster.  I've been doing testing and I'm getting the same thing.  I must be doing something wrong ... this repo has 2.6k stars, surely with that following the crowd must be right and we must be wrong??

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with `pyotp`, but browsing [through the code](https://github.com/nathforge/pyotp/blob/master/src/pyotp/totp.py), I came across this:

```
def timecode(self, for_time):
    i = time.mktime(for_time.timetuple())
    print(i, i/self.interval)
    return int(i / self.interval)
```

`timecode` is used to compare between different "otp"s and see if they are the same; `interval` has a default of 30.

Probably the idea is that within 30 seconds, the hashes result in the same. Unfortunately, the way this is coded, that doesn't seem to work: it will take some absolute time (well, w.r.t. 1970), and chop that up into 30 second intervals. The result of `timecode` is the amount of 30 second intervals since 1970. Of course, once the clock has passed `*:00` or `*:30`, a new 30 second interval starts and a mismatch arises. With a sleep time of 5 seconds and 10 trials, your program takes 50 seconds, so it's *almost* 2 times the 30 second boundary is crossed; hence 2 out of 10 when rounded to integer values (increase the sleep to 6 seconds and it will be exactly 2 out of 10 for a larger sample).

As I mentioned, I don't know `pyotp`, but it appears this is not intended, and it should really be an interval that is being compared (`datetime.timedelta` could help here). I just noticed [your bug report](https://github.com/nathforge/pyotp/issues/11), so feel free to provide a link there to this SO answer.

In the meantime, perhaps you should avoid `TOTP` and use another class; or set an incredibly long interval (e.g. `TOTP(key, interval=315360000)`, which is 10 years), depending on your needs.